# what is the best audio format for human voice ?

Tags: audio

Hi i am working on a compression audio stuff and i would like to ask you about the audio format the most adequate for human voice that can concerve the same quality of my files while trasfering to the server ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With standard audio formats, there's not much of a difference between music and speech compression. MP3, for example, is designed to only lose information that is largely imperceptible to the human ear, especially at high bit rates. MP3 is nice because can choose a bit rate that meets your data needs. If you need more extreme compression you'll definitely lose a noticeable amount of quality.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction the problem is that mp3 encoding is not supported natively with java so i have the choice between ogg vorbis or flac wich you think is better ?

Comment: FLAC is lossless, so if the files are small enough, it's definitely the way to go!

Comment: i cant define if the files would be small or not my app will be used by doctors in hospitals recording ther prescriptions and every thing they need to memorise.

Comment: If you don't have any idea of the amount of compression you need, how can we give you advice on which compressed file type to use? The tradeoff here is small file size vs. quality.

Comment: do you know any java library that i could use on my java applet in order to compress wav file to mp3/ogg vorbis file before sending it to server ?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to tune the flac codec, and it's seams overkill to use it for voice recording.

Even if mp3 is not supported natively with java, you should take a look at ["lame"](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) which is a CLI mp3 codec, very easy to use with Java (create a Process object, with the parameters you wants...)

usage:
`lame.exe -V2 file.wav file.mp3`

or from a wav buffer (if your application records the voice itself)
`lame.exe -V2 - file.mp3`

Comment: i have to implement a solution pure java in my case the user will not be able to install any thing so do you thing i can use the ogg vorbis format i heared about a library called jorbis ?

Comment: I don't want to annoy you, but lame doesn't require any installation. It's just an executable file which have to be near your java program at runtime. I don't know about jorbis, but I think ogg is just an encapsulating format. It will not (afaik) compress your data... Java doesn't natively handle media files well...

Comment: thanks for your reations .. i tried once to use lame but i found it very complicated bcoz i want do this after recording in my java applet and it have to work on all plate-forms (linux, windows, mac) and like we know lame is like a wrapper around ffmpeg wich doesn't work with the same way in all the SE... if you have any experience in this i will be very thankfull if you show me the way

Comment: I don't think it's a wrapper. And I think (not sure) that lame exists also for linux / osx. I'll edit my answer with one example.

Comment: ok i thing this is cmd .exe for windows and the cmd for linux is lame file.wav file.mp3 but it require installation

Comment: I know I've done this before. I thought I used JLayer, but maybe I am misremembering altogether.

Comment: As an alternative to MP3, you could use OGG Vorbis. Here is a link to the spi from javazoom: http://www.javazoom.net/vorbisspi/vorbisspi.html

Comment: how can i add jars into classpath of the runtime ?

Comment: hi Bjorn have you ever done this bfore with ogg vorbis cause i cant find the way to compress my wav files to this format using vorbisspi !! ?